# Use a wireless repeater to make a wired router wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, router, repeater

I have:

- a D-Link wireless repeater.
- a Linksys *wired* router.
- a Linksys *wireless* router.

My wired devices are not near my actual wireless router, so I can't plug them directly.

I would like to plug my repeater into the wired router to make it wireless, so my wired devices can be plugged into the router and use my existing wireless network.

I don't care of having to change the firmware.

Is that possible?

**EDIT**

The Linksys Wireless router is my main router, in which I have my internet connection. I don't have the model right now.

The Repeater is a D-Link DWL-G710

The wired router is a Linksys BEFSR81 version 3.

I would like to plug my repeater into the WIRED router. Then, I would like other devices (As a PAP2T) plugged in the WIRED router to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Making a wireless router into a "bridge" for your wired devices should be fairly easy to do, but it's hard to get specific when you don't include the model numbers for the equipment you already have.  Those devices have a dozen pages of setup options.  You get to them by browsing the device IP address.  Terminology is different for different devices and companies, so I can not go much further without model numbers.

For a LinkSys WRT54GL, for instance, the key is to change from "Gateway" to "Router" mode.